# Create Loop to use value from another table to perform deletions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out a way to create a loop that will grab an id from a column of a different table and use that id to perform deletions.

`@ID` represents a different ID from another table.  How can I create a loop to read through each ID and delete rows from other tables based off that ID?

```
Declare @ID int
Set @ID = dbo.control.id

Delete from dbo.search where id=@id
Delete from dbo.searchfolder where id=@id
Delete from dbo.application where id =@id
```

Comment: Unless you have other logic in the loop, you don't need one.  Just use a `join` in your `delete` statements.

Comment: The id will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need a loop ,just join will work,you can implement same logic for all tables

```
Delete s
from dbo.search s
join
dbo.content c
on c.id=s.id
```

You also can use exists,which may be faster in some scenarios depending on data density

```
delete from t2 where exists(select 1 from dbo.t1 where t1.id=t2.id)
```